# db2 SQL Query to Fix Inconsistent `DDMMYYYY` values to be `YYYYMMDD`

Tags: sql, date, db2

So I've got an integer column in db2 that represents a date field. This has inconsistent
formatting for a subset of the data, i.e. 2017-2019

| MDATE |
| --- |
| 20070730 |
| ... |
| 1012017 |
| ... |
| 31122019 |

The following would solve it, except for the existence of DDMYYYY entries..

```
select  
(CASE WHEN MDATE BETWEEN 1012017 and 31122019 and MDATE NOT BETWEEN 20070101 AND 20221031 THEN TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CHAR(MDATE),'DDMMYYYY')
ELSE TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CHAR(MDATE),'YYYYMMDD')
END) AS TIMESTAMP
from DATA.FCALENDAR
where MDATE BETWEEN 1012017 and 31122019
and MDATE NOT BETWEEN 20070101 AND 20221005
limit 10;
```

| MDATE |
| --- |
| 2007-08-07 00:00:00 |
| ... |
| 0017-12-10 00:00:00 |
| ... |
| 2019-12-31 00:00:00 |

Looking for a way that can handle all 3 cases above

Comment: To resolve the problem you should update your question with information on all possible formats for `MDATE BETWEEN 1012017 and 31122019`. That is, is that correct, that the only formats expected are `DDMMYYYY` and `DDMYYYY`? Is it possible to get, say, a value which must be treated as `DMMYYYY` in addition to these 2 above? If former, then the answer should be easy: just convert `DDMYYYY` to `DDMMYYYY` for a numbers with 7 digits for this branch of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH MYTAB (MDATE) AS 
(
VALUES
  20070730
, 1012017
, 31122019
)
SELECT 
  MDATE
, CASE 
    WHEN MDATE BETWEEN 1012017 and 31122019 and MDATE NOT BETWEEN 20070101 AND 20221031 
    THEN 
    --TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CHAR(MDATE),'DDMMYYYY')
      TIMESTAMP_FORMAT 
      (
        CASE LENGTH (TO_CHAR (MDATE))
          WHEN 7 THEN SUBSTR (TO_CHAR (MDATE), 1, 2) || '0' || SUBSTR (TO_CHAR (MDATE), 3)
          ELSE TO_CHAR (MDATE)
        END
      , 'DDMMYYYY'
      )
    ELSE TIMESTAMP_FORMAT(CHAR(MDATE),'YYYYMMDD')
  END AS TIMESTAMP
FROM MYTAB
```

| MDATE | TIMESTAMP |
| --- | --- |
| 20070730 | 2007-07-30-00.00.00.000000 |
| 1012017 | 2017-01-10-00.00.00.000000 |
| 31122019 | 2019-12-31-00.00.00.000000 |